# How to convert a simple string to Byte Array in VBA?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, string

I need to convert a simple string in a Byte array using excel VBA. Then this byte array is used as the request's body.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you only need ANSI characters, you can use the StrConv() function [as is done here](http://www.example-code.com/vb/stringToByteArray.asp).

Comment: To expand: Use `StrConv(<string>, vbFromUnicode, <optional locale>)` and assign the result to a *byte array*. Then each byte in the result corresponds to a character in the original string (they must be representable in the current locale). See also [vb6 - What does vbFromUnicode mean? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10389080/what-does-vbfromunicode-mean)

Comment: The link is dead, but from internet archive the code just had ``dim b() as byte``, then ``b = StrConv(myString,vbFromUnicode)``

Answer (score 31):

Matthew answered how to convert to ANSI, but if you wanted the resulting byte array to still represent the original Unicode string, you'd simply assign it directly:

```
Public Sub Main()
   Dim b() As Byte
   Dim s As String
   s = "Whatever"
   b = s  'Assign Unicode string to bytes.'
   s = b  'Works in reverse, too!'
   Debug.Print s
End Sub
```

That's all there is to it.  You end up with a 16-element Byte array, each successive pair describing one Unicode character.

Comment: To be precise, this makes the byte array equal to the UTF-16-LE encoding of the string content. Which means that each UTF-16 code unit corresponds to 2 bytes, however a character not in the BMP takes up 2 code units and thus 4 bytes.

Answer (score -1):

```
' a bit of an example
' had some strings down column  G
' nothing in columns "F" or "H"  so that current works
'  Think about it.. there are many many columns
' so leave blank columns on each side of setsof dats
' then currentregion works ... IFF no blank rows in the data
'
' problem to solve  some text  was  Fred3  John2 Blue3
' others were  Bert 3  Green 2 ... which was the require format
'  the ASC char 1 ..255 are the odd or even
'  numbered bytes if array is 1 based or 0 based
'
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim RV$, Ra As Range, Ri&, AL%, WSA() As Byte
    Dim Ci%, WS$, LV As Byte

    Set Ra = Range("g8").CurrentRegion
    For Ri = 1 To Ra.Rows.Count
        WSA = CStr(Ra(Ri, 1).value)
        AL = UBound(WSA)
        LV = WSA(AL - 1)  ' last char byte value
        If LV > 47 And LV < 58 Then    ' 0 to 9
            If WSA(AL - 3) <> 32 Then    ' no space " "
                ReDim Preserve WSA(AL + 2)    ' allow 1 more char
                WSA(AL - 3) = 32    ' put in space
                WSA(AL - 1) = LV    ' return char
                WS = WSA    ' back to a string
                Ra(Ri, 1) = WS  ' back to the cell
            End If
        End If
    Next Ri
End Sub

' of course  the normal VBAcommands  Instr len Mid replace  &
' would do the job ... but my brain is lazy and needed some exercise
```