# What does vbFromUnicode mean?

Tags: vb6

I am going through some old VB6 code and I come across statements like -

```
   TempArray() = StrConv(PassedString, vbFromUnicode)
```

What does this mean?

Comment: [I wrote a GitHub gist explain string types in VBA in more details](https://gist.github.com/user202729/0374a217610a31c260d7f3bf3b61c9ff)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It takes a unicode string (any string in VB is in Unicode) and converts it to a byte array, using the current system codepage for non-unicode programs.

- There will be one byte per character if it is a *single-byte* codepage (e.g. English and Western Europe 1252)
- There may be multiple bytes per character if it is a *multi-byte* code page (e.g. Simplified Chinese)

Characters not found in that codepage are replaced with question marks (`?`).

Comment: +1. But it will be *multiple* bytes per character on multibyte code pages, e.g. Chinese, Korean.

Comment: @MarkJ Can't reproduce that: `Dim b() As Byte: b = StrConv(ChrW$(&H818A&), vbFromUnicode): MsgBox UBound(b) - LBound(b) + 1`, result is `1`.

Comment: Really?? That's surprising. I'd try to reproduce it myself but haven't time right now. Did you change the default code page on the PC to match? (something like Control Panel, Regional Settings, Advanced - Language for non-Unicode programs. May require reboot.)

Comment: @MarkJ No, that's a Chinese character randomly picked from charmap. Ah, I see now what you meant. I understood you in the exactly opposite way. No, I never had a multibyte codepage as the language for non-Unicode programs. Perhaps you were right.

Comment: Not all Strings in VB6 are Unicode.  That's why we have functions such as LeftB$(), AscB(), etc. however if somebody is asking such fundamental questions as "what does vbFromUnicode mean" we probably don't need to go there.

Comment: @GSerg You have to change the default codepage. Otherwise you will be using a.codepage that doesn't support the character, and you will just get "?". So I think I'm right. But still without testing it myself

Comment: @MarkJ You are right; `StrConv(ChrW$(&H818A&), vbFromUnicode, &H0C04&)` gives 2 bytes. No need to change the system setting this way.

Comment: @BobRiemersma AFAIK all strings in VB6 are Unicode, UCS-2. This does not mean that all characters are 2 bytes; UCS-2 is a variable lenght encoding, so functions like `LeftB` exist to distinguish between bytes and characters.

Comment: @GSerg Have taken the liberty of editing your answer, changing the single byte part. BTW Bob is right and you can cause a VB6 string to contain non-Unicode data (e.g. "ANSI" string encoded for a particular code page).

Comment: @GSerg Not true at all. It is perfectly possible to create and work with 8-bit ANSI, ASCII, or any encoding you wish within a VB6 String. Unicode is just what you typically see using default operations, which makes it much more prevalent. The "B" functions are used to operate on such 8-bit character String values, and many of them can even operate on Byte arrays.