# Sending a String with Hex Commands to Serial Port in VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba, serial-port

First of all thanks for taking the time to read my question. Any advice would be appreciated. I am currently working on a VBA project in Excel. I have completed most of the Project but am stuck at an apparent small road block. 
A bit of back story. I am writing an Excel code to communicate with a PWM generator through a CANUSB. The device is attached to the computer via USB and is acting as a Virtual COM Port. I have to send it a pre configured/pre-determined command to actviate the PWM. I have first tested my commands while connected to a terminal Putty with the relevant com settings. The device is working with the terminal putty, but when i send the same command such as: t02180002F4012C01B80B (here only the first character is a "t" the rest are all supposed to be hex) the device/CANUSB does not send the command over to the PWM. The only problem i am seeing here is that while the terminal Putty is correctly interpreting or passing on the command, the excel vba program is either converting it to something else or not sending the proper string. I have also tried converting the hex to char, and also sending as a string. 
A little detail about the command that i am supposed to send. The first charachter is always t which is followed by a 8 byte size hex command (i.e. each byte is written in program as a hex command). 
Here is some of my code (for sending, with the other options used marked out as comments):

```
Private Sub PWM_cmd_Send(ByVal cmd As String)

    'I was first defining it as string then tried defining it as Variant
    Dim Hex_Cmd As Variant



   'Tried sending the direct whole command as input
    If cmd = "Push" Then
        Hex_Cmd_Final = "t02180002F4012C01B80B"

   'Another way of setting the command that didnt work
        'Hex_Cmd_Final = "t" & Chr(&H2) & Chr(&H18) & "0" & Chr(&H0) & "0" & Chr(&H2) & Chr(&HF4) & Chr(Hex_Cmd) & "0" & Chr(&H1) & Chr(&HB8) & "0" & Chr(&HB)

   'Another option that didnt work   
        'Hex_Cmd_Final = Chr("t") + &H0 + &H2 + &H1 + &H8 + &H0 + &H0 + &H0 + &H2 + &HF + &H4 + &H0 + &H1 + &H0 + &H2 + &HC + &H0 + &H1 + &HB + &H8 + &H0 + &HB + vbCr


    ElseIf cmd = "Pull" Then

        Hex_Cmd_Final = "t02180001F4012C01B80B" + vbCr

        'Hex_Cmd_Final = Chr("t") + &H0 + &H2 + &H1 + &H8 + &H0 + &H0 + &H0 + &H1 + &HF + &H4 + &H0 + &H1 + &H0 + &H2 + &HC + &H0 + &H1 + &HB + &H8 + &H0 + &HB + vbCr

        'Hex_Cmd_Final = "t" & "0" & Chr(&H2) & Chr(&H18) & "0" & Chr(&H0) & "0" & Chr(&H1) & Chr(&HF4) & Chr(Hex_Cmd) & "0" & Chr(&H1) & Chr(&HB8) & "0" & Chr(&HB)
    Else
        MsgBox ("Something is wrong, command not being read correctly")
    End If

    'The command message is then sent over to another sub to be fowarded
    'to the Virtual Com Port. 
    PWMcmdSend_Default (Hex_Cmd_Final)
End Sub
```

The Procedure PWMcmd_Default uses the
     `mclsComm2.Senden (cmd)`

which in turn sends the command using the following code lines (taken from the senden function defined in a module file)

```
    ' Text senden
   abyteBuffer = StrConv(Text, vbFromUnicode)
   lngRet = WriteFile(mlngComHandle, VarPtr(abyteBuffer(0)), Len(Text), lngWritten, 0)
```

If anyone has any suggestion, they would be welcome. Kind Regards

Comment: What you've got in your code is a simple `If` statement and a call to an unknown function. This isn't going to help anyone solve your problem, whatever that might be. Clarify your problem statement and include a [mcve] showing relevant code.

Comment: Your code sample is no help and wouldn't perform the work you've stated in your question.  Your problem is the data types you're using.  You've made an assumption about how the VBA engine stores strings.  Take look at this explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/998746/how-to-convert-a-simple-string-to-byte-array-in-vba). You're looking for an ASCII stream and your sending ANSI.

Comment: Thank you for the input, i was able to figure out that error was in the vbCr that i was including in the end. Apparently, i had by, checking another terminal program and CAN software, found out earlier that the HEX command B80B (in string in end) is acting as a end of line command, (i.e. as vbCr) as it is being appended to the end of the command input string. I dont know exactly why B80B as it doesnt translate to vbCr. Anyway by removing the vbCr being added to the end of the cmd string, i was able to get it to operate. Thx for those who took the time to read and reply to my post.